# Need to track page without product catalogue

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, einstein-recommendations

I have a question. Can I able to track the customer's view page, URL,clicks without uploading product catalogue in Einstein recommendation.

I know that we can track products page by uploading product catalogue.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Predictive Recommendations you will technically need a catalogue, unfortunately. This could just be a dummy catalogue for all intents and purposes, for example just with one entry. Once you have that, you can use all the other features you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You don't need a catalogue to track what the user does. The catalogue is simply your pool of content or products to recommend to the user as they browse/interact with your site.

But without a catalogue, you won't be able to make personalized recommendations since you'd have nothing to recommend.

Comment: A catalogue is a required, as page views on items not in catalogue will be discarded.

Comment: Where in the documentation is that? You can track page views on non-catalogued items because they provide documentation/examples for category pages, search pages, and a generic page view, none of which is tied explicitly to a catalogue item.

Comment: You are right, when it comes to viewing reports in Web & Mobile Analytics will be possible, but no metadata will be shown in reporting on browsed items, as this is taken from the catalogue. Also - integration with PI_ and IGO_ data extensions will not be possible without catalogue

Comment: I can confirm that setUserInfo only works with trackPageView, but you don't need an item in the trackPageView call, if you just want to track the user.